# Attempting to put the following conic into standard form: $y^2-2x^2+8y-8x-4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> Put the following conic into standard form: $y^2-2x^2+8y-8x-4=0$

I ended up with
$$
-\frac {(x-2)^2}{12} + \frac{(y+8)^2}{24} = 1,
$$
but I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: You should show the step in-between as that is where you'd be most likely to have error.

Comment: Show your steps. That doesn't look right to me

Comment: That's a hyperbola. Have you tried looking at a graph? Try Wolframalpha.

Comment: It isn't quite right. You should check over your steps and let us know which one(s) is (are) confusing you. This isn't the place for generic work-checking, but I'm sure people will be happy to assist with any specific confusion.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2-2x%5E2%2B8y-8x-4%3D0

Answer (score 2):

$$
y^2 -2x^2 + 8y - 8x - 4 = 0 \implies (y^2 + 8y + 16 - 16) - 2(x^2 + 4x + 4 - 4) - 4 = 0 \implies \\
(y + 4)^2 - 2(x+2)^2 - 16 + 8 - 4 = 0 \implies (y+4)^2 - 2(x+2)^2 = 12 \implies \\
-\frac {(x+2)^2}6 + \frac {(y+4)^2}{12} = 1
$$